# Following vue-stripe directions causes Webpack to give warning "export 'StripeCheckout' was not found in 'vue-stripe'"

Tags: laravel, webpack, vue.js, stripe-payments, laravel-mix

While following the `vue-stripe` [installation directions](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-stripe), which mainly consists of a simple `import { StripeCheckout } from 'vue-stripe'` I received the following warning from Webpack:

```
"export 'StripeCheckout' was not found in 'vue-stripe'
```

(Technically I am using `laravel-mix` as a wrapper around Webpack.)

I have no clue why it isn't working. Everything on my system is reasonably up-to-date. It's a Laravel 5.4 app on the back-end with a SPA on the front-end using Vue 2 and `vue-router`, and it uses `yarn` instead of `npm`, with a lot of Vue components.

Answer (score 0):

This [issue from the `vue-stripe` repo](https://github.com/matfish2/vue-stripe/issues/24) might be useful here:

> You can work around this by doing something like
>
> `import Stripe from 'vue-stripe'`
>
> `components: {'stripe-checkout': Stripe.StripeCheckout, 'bus': StripeCheckout.Bus}`

Comment: Thanks. I think this is incorrect. (StripeCheckout.Bus should be Stripe.Bus, I think.) Either way, this does get rid of the Webpack warning, but now my browser says that "Vue is not a constructor" and nothing works.

Comment: Hmm, well, this might be question better posed on the `vue-stripe` repo then, since it's very likely quite specific to `vue-stripe`.